# Can I find out what resistance bacteria has based on strain? where do I look for that info?

Tags: bacteriology, antibiotics, antibiotic-resistance, information

I have a list of strains across various organisms for example:

Escherichia coli - ATCC 25922, CGSC 6152, W3110RL.

Pseudomonas aeruginosa - ATCC 27853, PAO1, APAE1111.

I'm failing to find any resistance information on these strains, as in what strain is resistant or susceptible to what antibiotic. Is there a way to find out?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many official websites that holds information and collection of microbial strains, here you can find a selection of them: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4241729/

Comment: @Dirigible Answers should be in answers rather than comments.

Comment: @Dom, are you looking for a database of resistance genes carried by these strains, or do you want information on minimum inhibitory concentrations?

Comment: Start with the ATCC product sheets (Just google the ATCC Number). They have lots of information about common uses, history of the strain, references, and sometimes some antibiotic susceptibility info. Keep in mind, if it has been kicking around a lab for a while, you might want to double check some of the MIC values, as they're known to change with serial passaging in broth cultures. But that's mostly if you need rather exact values.

Answer (score 1):

If database and literature searches fail, you can plug the GenBank accession numbers for your genomes into the CARD [Resistance Gene Identifier](https://card.mcmaster.ca/analyze/rgi). It takes either protein or nucleotide sequences, though nucleotide seqs. undergo ORF calling first. For example, plugging in [NZ_CP009072.1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_CP009072.1) for *E. coli* ATCC 25922 gives 7 perfect hits to known antibiotic resistance genes. Granted, carrying the genetic determinants of resistance is different from phenotypic resistance, but it's a place to start.